# Mysql Index for date fields

Tags: mysql, performance, date, indexing

I have a datetime column and I have to filter by date and group it by day or month. This is a million rows table.

```
|IssueDate          |
--------------------
|2015-11-24 16:46:00|
```

This is the first choice without any index because I always must use a date function:

```
select * from myTable where DATE(IssueDate)='2015-11-24'
select * from myTable group by DATE(IssueDate)
select * from myTable group by YEAR(IssueDate), MONTH(IssueDate)
```

This is the second choice, to separate time and date in the table:

```
|IssueDate |Issuetime|
----------------------
|2015-11-24|16:46:00 |
```

Here I can index the date field:

```
select * from myTable where IssueDate='2015-11-24'
select * from myTable group by IssueDate
select * from myTable group by YEAR(IssueDate), MONTH(IssueDate)
```

Another try with redundancy fest:

```
|IssueDate |Issuetime|IssueMonth|IssueYear|
-------------------------------------------
|2015-11-24|16:46:00 |11        |2015     |
```

Here I can index all my fields:

```
select * from myTable where IssueDate='2015-11-24'
select * from myTable group by IssueDate
select * from myTable group by IssueYear, IssueMonth
```

What is the way to index this for the **best performance**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your issue is writing queries so they can use indexes.

Instead of writing:

```
select *
from myTable
where DATE(IssueDate) = '2015-11-24';
```

Try:

```
select *
from myTable
where IssueDate >= '2015-11-24' AND IssueDate < '2015-11-25';
```

Your other two examples use `group by`.  I find that it is quite hard to get MySQL to use an index for aggregation in a query.

Comment: And by "quite hard" you can read: it only works for MIN and MAX with specific JOINs and WHERE...

Comment: If I need for find (and not group) by month and year I think that should be the same as you suggested for date: where IssueDate >= '2015-11-01' AND IssueDate < '2015-11-30';

Comment: @Tobia Yes, a single index on a `datetime` will be sufficient for filtering.

Comment: Are there any advantages to divide date part from time part (in these cases or any other scenario)? For example if I need only a equal filter (date='2015-11-24' ) instead of between filter (IssueDate >= '2015-11-24' AND IssueDate < '2015-11-25')

Comment: A separate date field (and index) helps if you need to join on a date or retrieve a min/max group by date. But it can be added later with only a schema/trigger change. The performance difference between `=` and `BETWEEN` will be marginal.

Comment: I prefer the pattern:  `d >= '2015-11-24' AND d < '2015-11-24' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.  It avoids all sort of problems, such as leap year.  (Note that @Tobia solution accidentally failed to include the last day of Nov.)